Add spacing around datalabels in React Apexcharts library
I am using React Apexcharts library to plot the chart. I am having trouble adding space around the datalabels in a pie chart. Can anyone help in this?
const pieChartOptions = {
    labels: ["Above Ground", "Under Ground", "Divider"],
    chart: {
      width: "50px",
    },
    colors: ["#FF8C33", "#4472C4", "#EFF4FB"],
    states: {
      hover: {
        filter: {
          type: "none",
        },
      },
    },
    legend: {
      show: false,
    },
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      formatter: function (val, opts) {
        return opts.w.globals.series[opts.seriesIndex];
      },
      style: {
        fontSize: "18px",
      },
      dropShadow: {
        enabled: true,
        left: 2,
        top: 2,
        opacity: 0.7,
      },
    },
    hover: { mode: null },
    plotOptions: {
      donut: {
        expandOnClick: false,
        donut: {
          labels: {
            show: false,
          },
        },
      },
    },
    fill: {
      colors: ["#FF8C33", "#4472C4", "#EFF4FB"],
    },
    tooltip: {
      enabled: true,
      theme: "dark",
    },
  };

Is there any property that I can add to my dataLabels to achieve the spacing? I tried adding offsetX and offsetY but didn't work. 

For donut and pie charts you can use the offset property. Negative values will move the labels further inside, and positive values will move it further outside.
options = {
  plotOptions: {
    pie: {
      dataLabels: {
        offset: -50
      }
    }
  }
}

The offsetX and offsetY properties adjust the offset to the left and above the entire donut/pie area respectively.
